# Want to have a square struct with generic type and then find area via impl?

Tags: generics, rust

```
struct Sqr<T> {
    len: T,
    // wid: T,
}

impl<T> Sqr<T> {
    fn mult(self, other: Sqr<T>) -> T {
        self.len * other.len // error here.
        // error is : cannot multiply `T` to `T`
    }
}
```

self.len is of type T, how to add or multiply 2 variables of type T.?

Comment: See the [`std::ops::Mul`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Mul.html) trait. You might want to add a `T: std::ops::Mul` bound to the `impl`.

Comment: The compiler itself tells you the solution in the error message: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a65bdcac9f35067d2178f74692ad9931 "consider restricting type parameter `T`"

Answer (score 1):

In your code you multiply two variables of generic type T, but they might not implement the Mul trait for multiplication. Therefore, you need to explicitly require them to implement the Mul trait, as such:

```
impl<T> Sqr<T> where
    T: std::ops::Mul<T, Output = T> {
    fn mult(self, other: Sqr<T>) -> T {
        self.len * other.len 
    }
}
```

For more information on this topic, you can refer to Rust By Example's "Generics" chapter - especially [Bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/bounds.html).

Comment: How to implement the same to find the area?
  ` fn area(self) -> T {
        self.len * self.len // this is giving error
    } `

Comment: One solution would be to add the Copy trait to the bound (`T: std::ops::Mul<T, Output = T> + Copy`)

Comment: I thought #derive[Copy, Debug] would be enough. 
basically, I didn't understand whats happening
I'm new to rust. reading the docs didn't help.

Comment: @TechyTech  Adding `#derive[Copy, Debug]` to the struct means the struct derives the Copy and Debug traits, but in this case you need your generic type `T` to implement those traits, because you multiply `T` and `T`, not `Sqr` and `Sqr`